# Tenant Listener Load Once in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi I have an event listener that checks the subdomain to determine the tenant in my Symfony2 application.  The service config is:

```
services:
    acme.tenant.tenantlistener:
        class: Acme\TenantBundle\Services\TenantListener
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: checkTenant }
```

The problem is that this listener runs every time I load any controller action.  So if I call a controller method from Twig, it runs, resulting in many unnecessary hits on the database.  Is there a way to have this listener run only once, at the very beginning of the master request?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to register a listener only for master requests. But there is a way you can use to make your code run only once. Place the following code in your listener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST == $event->getRequestType()) {
        // place your code here so it will run only for master requests

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true. Here is doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events

Comment: Thanks guys that did the trick, thanks NHG for that link to the internals, I had to use HttpKernelInterface to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I corrected my code snippet. Seems like I didn't use the newest Symfony doc.